# Eclipse Plugin/Product CommonNavigator

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to build a plugin/product based on common navigator;
 1. Subclassed CommonNavigator
 2. Defined view in plugin.xml
 3. Added view in perspectiveExtension
 4. Defined Navigator content as;

```
      <navigatorContent
        contentProvider=".views.providers.ImageBankContentProvider"
        id=".views.providers.ImageBankContentProvider"
        labelProvider=".views.providers.ImageBankContentLabelProvider"
        name="name">
        <enablement>
            <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath" />
        </enablement>            
     </navigatorContent>
```

and the navigator list file structure, my problem is i want add Virtual resources in file tree, grouping file under virtual folders.

Q1, How will i do it?
Q2, Since it will be a product which do not have a concept of project, i need to provide a mechanism to import filesyetm into common navigator view, How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the 5 articles by MICHAEL D. ELDER - http://scribbledideas.blogspot.com/2006/06/ - although they are rather old, they are still current.

**UPDATE**: As @Zafar rightly noted, I forgot the last important article by [Simon Zambrovski](http://www.techjava.de/topics/2009/04/eclipse-common-navigator-framework/) which talks about "Minimal non-resource based CNF viewer". This article also includes a number of good references at the botton. Sorry about missing link...

Comment: These tutorial are about creating TreeViewer using CNF, but has no clue how to add VirtualResource